# Filtering the Data in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a project in AngularJs. I have problem while filtering data. Data is coming from API in the form of 0 and 1. I am showing the data in conditional form like:

ng-if = 0 ; Internal
ng-if = 1; External

My problem is that the data is filtered when I type 0 and 1 in search box, but I want data should be filtered when I type  internal and external in search box.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="customersFlowsList.linkStatus" class="flow_filter_searchbox">
    <li ng-repeat="customersFlowsList in customersFlows | filter:{linkStatus:customersFlowsList.linkStatus} | unique:'linkStatus'">

     <div class="check_box">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox2"  ng-model="filterLink[customersFlowsList.linkStatus]">
        <label for="checkbox1"><span for="checkbox1">{{customersFlowsList.linkStatus | contractStatusName}}</span></label>
     </div>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple custom filter function to do this. Some sample code might look like this:

```
  $scope.filterFn = function(item){
    if($scope.search.Mode == "external"){
       return item.Mode == 1 
  }
    else if ($scope.search.Mode == "internal"){
       return item.Mode == 0;
  }
  else return false;

};
```

Then replace your filter in your ng-repeat with the new filter function

```
ng-repeat="item in items | filter: filterFn"
```

Also, another option could be to replace the property on the data when you receive it from 0 and 1 to internal or external, then your original search would work.